# How do I prevent internet explorer from rewriting my text?

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer

I have a javascript variable that contains an url, populated by outputting a script tag from php. The intention is to change the webpage to that url under certain circumstances.

`var url = "/somepage?q=3&region=1";`

The problem is that the url contains the sequence "&reg" which internet explorer changes to "®" without being asked.

I've tried escaping the whole url with htmlspecialchars, which breaks other browsers. Turning off quirks mode might help, but it's not an option with the current system. Adding  to the script tag did nothing.

edit:
I figured out one solution, "escaping" the url with concatenation.

`var url = '<?php implode( "&'+'", explode( '&', '/somepage?q=3&region=1' ) ); ?>';`

I also realized I should probably mention how I change the page:

`document.location.href = url;`

edit:
Turns out I had an error in my script tag. A minimal example that shows the same "problem":

```
<script type="text/javascript" />
    var url = "/test?mode=preview®ion=1";
</script>
```

The self-closing start tag is the important thing here.

Comment: Does it *work* with the ® sign? IE sometimes does these sort of things, but it doesn't break the behavior (sometimes).

Comment: IE is always a bit nutty. Are you able to just output the URL as "/somepage?region=1&q=3" instead?

Comment: What are you doing with this JS? Does it go anywhere near `innerHTML`?

Comment: can you please show the relevant HTML code including the `<script>` tag? I'm asking because that code snipped you posted should work fine in any browser, including IE.

Comment: @Blender No, it does not work.

Comment: Can't you redirect directly in PHP using `header()`?

Comment: @Aaron Hathaway I could reorder the url, but I'd always live in fear of an url with two problems.

Comment: The actual script choses one url from a whole list of urls based on the users choice of a variable number of select elements. Posting the whole code would be a bit impractical, but I'll try to poke around and find a minimal example that fails as expected.

Comment: This problem isn't specific to PHP or IE.  It happens in all browsers with or without scripting.  I'm trying to figure it out myself with no luck, but it seems that browsers are "translating" &reg to ® without looking for the trailing slash.  Here is an example: (sorry it's a Google search link, it's what I'm trying to track down).  Well, crap, the link is too long for this box

Comment: http://www.google.com/aclk?sa=l&ai=CeNrm1vhJUf3gIu3kiQKi6oDoB7iOsooDwLyYk0mT_tLPUAgAEAEgtlQoA1CX7rjY-f____8BYMn2-IbIo6AZoAHghaz1A8gBAaoEKE_QjFYZblXjHTyrWHskROpntct5DZbok3_k4LapLCUISICQDNr34cuABZBOgAeI-tMK&sig=AOD64_3coT2vLXSg5mTrKPMvJ_FQMyEfqw&ved=0CDMQ0Qw&adurl=https://devc.fuzebox.com/freetrial%3Futm_source%3DSEM-Google%26network%3DSearch%26utm_campaign%3DScreen-Share%26ag%3DScreen-Share-General%26q%3D%252Bscreen%2520%252Bsharing%26utm_content%3D19593432016%26region%3DUS%26offer%3Dfree-trial%26utm_term%3D%252Bscreen%2520%252Bsharing%26utm_medium%3Dcpc&rct=j&q=screen+sharing+tool+for+online

Answer (score 4):

It should be `var url = "/somepage?q=3&amp;region=1";`

Always use `&amp;` in URLs so the browser understands this a query separator and doesn't think it refers to some htmlentity (the problem here is IE doesn't care if the semicolon is present or not and assumes `&reg` should be `&reg;`)

EDIT: the real context was added after I answered and as pointed out in the question itself and in comments, you shouldn't use `&amp;` if you intend to use the variable to redirect using some `window.location`

BUT, since we have PHP at hand, I would suggest using some PHP code like this if the javascript redirect is not part of some other complex script:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://domain/somepage?q=3&region=1');
exit();
?>
```

Comment: But isn't the ampersand denoting a new PHP variable?

Comment: No. `$` starts a PHP variable. `&` starts an HTML entity … but not inside a `<script>` element.

Comment: And in a PHP context, ampersand is the reference operator, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php#language.references.whatdo.assign but this is obviously javascript here.

Comment: @Udo it is if you intend to pass this value to the href attribute of some link but I didn't have this info when writing my answer.